# Python 3 Is there anything that prints the order of a class's method calls?

Tags: python, django

Yes, I can manually add a line of `print("call xxx")` to the start of the definition code of each method. But this seems a little silly.

For example:

```
class Test():
    def a(self):
        return self.b()
    def b(self):
        return self.c()
    def c(self):
        return
```

And when you process `Test` with something `X`,  and then you call `Test().a()`, the console will print something like:

```
call -> a
call -> b
call -> c
```

So you can see how method `a` calls other mothods, this is helpful for understanding the logic of some complicated Classes (such as Django's `ListView`)

At first, I use metaclass to make `X`, that is:

```
import functools

def print_info(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def magic(*args,**kwargs):
        print('call -> %s'%func.__name__)
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return magic

class BlackMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, parents, attrs):
        new_attrs={}
        for k,v in attrs.items():
            if callable(v):
                new_attrs[k] = print_info(v)
            else:
                new_attrs[k] = v
        return type.__new__(cls, name, parents, new_attrs)

class Test(metaclass=BlackMeta):
    def a(self):
        return self.b()
    def b(self):
        return self.c()
    def c(self):
        return
```

it works. But when I add `BlackMeta` to a subclass of  `DetailView`, and call method `get`, error raised:

[image]

So I give up and come here for help. Not necessarily a metaclass, anything that can show me the method call order is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `inspect` module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html). This allows you to view the stack and see what the parent calling chain is.

```
import inspect

class Test():
    def a(self):
        return self.b()

    def b(self):
        return self.c()

    def c(self):
        print inspect.stack()[0]
        print inspect.stack()[1]
        print inspect.stack()[2]
        return

Test().a()
```

This will print out:

```
(<frame object at 0x100271400>, 'test.py', 9, 'c', ['        print inspect.stack()[0]\n'], 0)
(<frame object at 0x10025dc60>, 'test.py', 7, 'b', ['        return self.c()\n'], 0)
(<frame object at 0x100273a40>, 'test.py', 5, 'a', ['        return self.b()\n'], 0)
```

In each case, the function name is 4th item in each tuple, and obviously as you go deeper into the stack, the further back you trace the execution chain.

The inspect module allows for all sorts of introspection and is a good choice if you want to untangle the logic of complicated code.

Comment: Best add as few as possible lines to the definition code, but thanks still

Comment: @Pythoner In your case, the answer by RichieHindle would seem more appropriate, but the inspect module can be very useful.

Comment: Actually, yours is more appropriate. I just need to find the last method, and add a line `[print(i[3]) for i in __import__("inspect").stack()]`. So thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sys.settrace` to register a function that gets called whenever a function gets called, like this:

```
import sys

def trace(frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'call':
        print("%s (%s line %d)" % (frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_lineno))
    return trace

class Test():
    def a(self):
        return self.b()
    def b(self):
        return self.c()
    def c(self):
        return 

def do_stuff():
   t = Test()
   t.a()

sys.settrace(trace)
do_stuff()
```

Output:

```
do_stuff (x.py line 16)
a (x.py line 9)
b (x.py line 11)
c (x.py line 13)
```

Your trace function will be called whenever any function gets called anywhere, so the naive 
version here will produce a lot of output in a non-trival program!  You'd need to only print the output when it was relevant, eg. by looking at `frame.f_code.co_filename`.

Comment: How do I apply this to the runtime method call of a classview of django project?

Comment: @Pythoner: Good question; you need to call `settrace` somewhere early on.  I'm not a Django guy, but I think the answer is probably to do it in your WSGI script (as specified in the Apache configuration file).  This article might give enough clues: http://johntron.github.io/programming/interactively-debug-django-applications/